# Getting Last Day of Month (2 Months Ago) in ODBC

Tags: sql, odbc, ssms, dbx

I'm trying to get the last day of 2 months ago on an **ODBC** server but can't seem to get it quite right as the EOMONTH built-in function of **SSMS** is not functional in **ODBC**.

The part of the code that I currently have in my **WHERE** clause returns the 1st day of the last month. I'm trying to get the day before that, which would be as described, the last day of 2 months ago.

**Here's the code that I'm currently using:**

```
WHERE x_date = cast(dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate())) as date)
```

Currently, we are May 7th, 2021. That **WHERE** clause returns me April 1st, 2021. I would like it to return me March 31st, 2021.

I've tried other **WHERE** clauses, without any positive results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `EOMONTH` function in sql server :

```
SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2)
```

if it is not supported then this should work:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,-1,getdate()))),DATEADD(mm,-1,getdate()))
```

by open day if you mean weekdays:

```
select case  DATENAME(weekday , <above date>)
        when  'Saturday' then dateadd(day , 2 , <above date>)
        when  'sunday' then dateadd(day , 1 , <above date>)
        else  <above date>
```

Comment: Hi eshirvana, that function is not available in ODBC which is why I mentioned it in my question. I can use it definitely is SSMS, but not in ODBC unfortunately.

Comment: I have another question if possible. Is there a way to integrate the last open day of the past month or past 2 months instead of just the last day of the month by any chance?

Comment: Hi @eshirvana, could you please elaborate on your third answer with the CASE? It doesn`t seem to be working in my WHERE clause

Comment: @onetharise there were extra = inside case , I removed it , now it should be ok